# Visualizing Weather Data in real-time/online with QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, weather, online, real-time

I have been searching for quite some time now, but I can't seem to find the answer by myself.

I did come across some things that helped me a bit, but many answers on this topic were from quite some time ago and I am curious if you might know some other (better) solutions now.

I want to visualize weather data with QGIS. Think about temperature, wind, etc.

The data will be stored in a Postgres or MySQL database.

**The goal** will be to publish the map real-time, online.

Every couple of minutes or so there will be new data stored in the database and all the latest data has to be shown on the map. There will be a slider so that a time can be selected and the map will show the weather data from that specific moment.

Do you guys have any ideas that might help me? I would love to hear them.

EDIT:

I will try to explain a bit better.

I am looking for some advice on how to approach my problem.

1. I have weather data that needs to be visualized using a GIS-tool. (I am planning on using QGIS). (This I know how to do.)
2. The data is updated regularly and QGIS needs to update the map when the data gets updated in the database.
3. Apart from that the map needs to be accessible via a webbrowser (local). The map shown in the webbrowser should be interactive and should show the map with the latest data.

So I have 2 questions actually:
- How do I make sure the map updates as soon as the data in the database updates?
- How do I get the map in the webbrowser and make sure the map is up to date and interactive?

Comment: Your project seems pretty vague, I don't know where to start. Are you looking for technical help or just global advice ? Is it online cartography or does it only concern data processing  ? You may have better answers being more precise on tools, data, constraints etc.

Comment: I just edited my question. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: If it is still unclear, please let me know!

Comment: If the goal is to publish the map online, what role does QGIS play? Why not use a webmap service right from the start?

Comment: What webmap service would you recommend then? I thought I needed QGIS to make the maps.

Comment: What format is your weather data in?  Is this observations, doppler, or weather model outputs?

Comment: My weather data is now a MySQL database, but I would like it to be in a postgres database because that has the postgis extension. I just need to convince the company for which I am developing this that postgis is much better for this project. In the database there are different station types and there is a timestamp for the data, also there is a column that contains the time when that data was last changed. The lat lon are now decimal values, which probably does not work with GIS apps.

Comment: @Thomas it is observations data